# Question mark in Java generics

Tags: java, generics, set, wildcard

I have read that `<?>` is exactly the same as `<? extends Object>`. Then what is the difference between:

1. `Set<?>`
2. `Set<Object>`
3. `Set`

I've tried adding `String.class` and `MyClass.class` into all these sets but in the second case it doesn't compile.

Another example I don't get is:

1. `Set<Class>`
2. `Set<Class<?>>`

To me it seems they are identical but if I have a method which returns `Set<Class<?>>`, I can't assign it's return value to variable of type `Set<Class>`.

I am sorry if this is duplicate, but I have read all the other posts and there are very few examples and I still can't understand it.

Comment: "I've tried adding String.class and MyClass.class into all these sets but in the second case it doesn't compile" , are you sure , i think the first case shouldn't compile

Comment: @Tomas linked a good resource [below:](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20various%20multi-level%20instantiations?)

Answer (score 7):

with `Set<?>` , i can use any type i want like : `Set<?> s  =new HashSet<Intger>()` or `Set<?> s  =new HashSet<String>()`.Since, i can make `?` refer to anything i'm not allowed to put anything other than `null` in the collection and i will get `Object` out of the collection.

`Set<Object>` says i can only assign type `Object` for ex : `Set<Object> s  =new HashSet<Object>()` but not `Set<Object> s  =new HashSet<String>()`.In this case i can add any type because `Object` is the super base type but i will get `Object` out of the collection.

`Set` is the basic raw type , you can add anything and get an `Object` type out of it.

`Set<Class>` is different than `Set<Class<?>>` .The first one says "I am a Set of non specific `Class` types " while the second one says "I am a Set of some specific `Class` types but don't know which".

Answer (score 0):

1. Using generic classes without their generic parameters (like `Set` and `Class`, and, by extension, `Set<Class>`) is a bad practice, to be avoided at all costs. If a class is generic, always use its generic form. If your IDE/compiler is not giving you big fat warnings when you try to use them, then you do not have sufficient warnings enabled.

[image: Austin Powers - I noticed you ignore compiler warnings; I too like to live dangerously.]

2. `Set<?>` is a set of virtually anything, but explicitly defined to be a set of nothing in particular, so it is practically unusable.  Don't do it.

So, you should *never* try to "assign [the] return value [of a method which returns `Set<Class<?>>`] to variable of type `Set<Class>`", because you should *never* have a variable of type `Set<Class>`, you should only have a variable of type `Set<Class<?>>`.

Better yet, try to have a variable of type `Set<Class<? extends MyClass>>` if applicable to your situation.  The more specific, the better.

Also, notice the following:

```
    //invalid (gives errors)
    Set<?> foo1 = new HashSet<>();
    foo1.add( String.class ); //error: cannot convert to capture<?>
    foo1.add( Generics2.class ); //error: cannot convert to capture<?>

    //perfectly fine, though lame (don't use `Object`, use something specific)
    Set<Object> foo2 = new HashSet<>();
    foo2.add( String.class );
    foo2.add( Generics2.class );

    //invalid (gives warnings, in my opinion it should give errors.)
    Set foo3 = new HashSet<>(); //warning "raw use of parameterized class 'foo3'"
    foo3.add( String.class ); //warning "unchecked call to member of raw type"
    foo3.add( Generics2.class ); //warning "unchecked call to member of raw type"
```

Comment: The reason raw classes are allowed is backward compatibility. They shouldn't therefore be considered errors by the compiler (although it's often a good idea to set your IDE to be stricter than the Java compiler)

Comment: @biziclop well, you are right.  I meant this as an option.  For example, the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler has a "treat warnings as errors" option. That's what I meant.

Comment: IDEs like Eclipse offer you this option too. They can be clever about it too, allowing you to call an external library that uses raw types in its API, but not when interacting with code in the same project.